# Reusing Dublin Core Ontology

Tags: ontology, protege, dublin-core

I'm new in ontology and i'm using protege to create my own. I have imported the Dublin core ontology (http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1) into my own ontology using protege but only annotations were included. Upon reading the documentation of Dublin core there were classes and properties defined. how will i include these classes and properties in my ontology with the use of protege?

Comment: Your post contains two questions that don’t seem closely related. I think it would be best to [edit] your second question out, and create a separate question post for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't look inside the files. Dublin Core has many files. The one that you are referring to ([elements](http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1)) only contains annotations. You need to find the appropriate file. The [DC terms](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/) contains some properties and classes. You need to read the documentation and then import the file with the modelling elements that you require.